# page does not reconize external js file

Tags: javascript

I have one html file that calls external js file. I am presume html file does not reconize

external js file Since firebug throws error of 'myfunction() is not defined'.

Here is my code in external js file.

```
function a(){
      //just function
}
```

and here is html file that makes trouble.

```
<script type="javascript/text" src="./myjs.js"></script>
<script>
    a();
</script>
```

can anybody tell me why I can't implement this simplest js file? when I run html file on 
python simpleHTTPServer, it even does not threw 404 error. 
I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: what does the network tab tell you?

Comment: only message i got is '200'. what is '200'?

Comment: 200 is the HTTP status code for 'OK'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. There must be something wrong with your path or your JS-File!

Answer (score 3):

The (old) MIME type for JavaScript was `text/javascript`, not `javascript/text`.

The browser will consider `javascript/text` to be an unknown scripting language and not execute it.

You appear to be using HTML 5 (since you are omitting the `type` attribute on the second script element). Omit it on all your script elements.

Comment: opps.... sorry. I did typo. in my code file, it is declared as 'text/javascript'.. but it still not working.. thx for advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check with firebug or chrome debugger if your js file path is correct and if it's correctly loaded.

You can see that in the "network" tab.

Comment: firebug indicates a() is not defined which is defined from myjs.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that my.js is not loaded when you accessed the function. Try using the function in Firebug or something.

Answer (score 0):

I could not load the function from js file because the function itself has an error.